# Align horizontal UL and DIV

Tags: html, css

I have a problem to align horizontaly DIV and UL, check the fiddle : [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/tfc5rgav/1/)

You can see DIV and UL are not on the same line.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="box-header">
        <h4 class="box-title">Title</h4>
    </div>
    <ul id="menuOnglet" class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="active">Elem1</li>
        <li>Elem2</li>
        <li>Elem3</li>
    </ul>
</div>

#menuOnglet{width:300px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:0;}
```

I don't want to wrap my UL with another DIV. Thanks !

Comment: Float the box header div left

Comment: Like this ? http://www.bootply.com/nLe7ko4lda this is align horizontal... I s on the same line just use col classes or pull

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a simple CSS declaration:

```
div, ul, li {
    display: inline-block;    /* this will align all div, ul, li elements on the webpage horizontally */
}
```

```css
#menuOnglet{width:300px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:0;}

div, ul, li {
    display: inline-block;    
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="box-header">
        <h4 class="box-title">Fiche contact : Jean paul</h4>
    </div>
    <ul id="menuOnglet" class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="active">Elem1</li>
        <li>Elem2</li>
        <li>Elem3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/tfc5rgav/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#menuOnglet{width:100px; margin: 0 auto;}
.box-header{text-align:center;}
```